# Parameter estimation with GMM

Tags: regression, normal-distribution

I have estimated the parameters of normal distribution with GMM 
and got the follwing results :

mean = -0.01168 , p-value = 0.83519

i'm bit confused in interpreting the result. can i say that the mean is zero as it is not statistically significant.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot say it is 0. All you can say is that there is not much evidence that it isn't 0. More precisely, a p-value of 0.84 means that, if, in the population from which this sample was drawn there was no effect at all, the probability of getting a test statistic at least as extreme as this one, in a sample the size of the one drawn, is 0.84.

Comment: thanks , and the $Sd = 1.77$ with $p value = 0.0000$ how can i interpret this parameter

Comment: I can't tell for sure what Sd is, from what you've written.

Comment: sd = standard deviation.

Comment: secondly can we say that mean is stable with respect to time ?

Comment: For us to be able to say what these mean, in any practical sense, you need to tell us a lot more. What are you modeling? What is your DV and IVs? Your last comment makes no sense with your origianl post, which is about a normal distribution and says nothing about time.